# AWS ECS service time period for checking and placing task in a container instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I scaled down my  EC2 instance count to zero in ECS Container for testing purpose and task count mentioned in the  ECS service is still 3 unchanged. Now i can see events happening in event tab, the service will try to place 3 task in containers and fail obviously because there is no container instance exist due to instance count is zero.Please see the below image

[image]

Now my query is :

1) What is the time period difference in which the service will try to place the task in a container instance . please see the image for time period gap.

2) When i scale up the instance count from zero to 3,  will the task place in the container instance at the same time or it will wait for the next time period check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time period difference is defined by the service throttle logic as explained here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-throttle-logic.html

as for the second part, it will place the tasks in the instances at the next scheduled retry. Hope this helps!